# Finding powers of (x+1)

Tags: dart

It appears to me that this has been before in all languages except dart...

Referenced in order btw, any improvements, any tips, any feed back would be appreciated...

````
// The Goal: raise (x + 1) to a power and get a list of strings output

final int power = 6; //determines which power
final String firstVar = "y"; //
final int secondNumber = 1;

void main() {
  //reference first

  List<List<double>> pyrmide = [
    [1], // anything to the power of zero is one
    [1,1]]; // needs [1,1] to work properly

  //reference second

  for(int i = 1; i < power // this builds the pyrmide
      ; i += 1) { 
    List<double> nextLayer = [1,1]; // outside numbers

    for(int j = 0; j < (pyrmide.length - 1); // finds inside numbers
        j += 1) {
       nextLayer
         .insert(j + 1,
          pyrmide[i][j] + pyrmide[i][j + 1] // finds number from the above layers
          );
    }

    pyrmide.add(nextLayer); // adds to the pyrmide next layer to be found
  }

  List<String> output = []; // will output something similar to ["x^2", "2x", "1"]

  //reference third

  for(int k = 0; // k finds the power of secondvar
      k < pyrmide.length; k += 1) {
    int l = power - k; // finds the power of firstvar

    if (l != 0 && k != 0) // don't want x^0 or 1x^power
    {
    output.add("${(pyrmide[power][k]*secondNumber).toString()}$firstVar^${l.toString()}");
    } else if (l == 0) {
      output.add("${(pyrmide[power][k] * secondNumber).toString()}");
    } else if (k == 0) {
      output.add("$firstVar^$l");
    }
  }

  print(output);
}

  /* it turns that pyrmides predicts powers of (x+1)
   power of zero: 1
   power of one: 1,1 (x + 1)
   power of two: 1, 2, 1 (x^2 + 2x + 1)
  */

  /* write the pyrmide down, the outside numbers are always one
   you only have to find 1 inside number for the power of 2, 2 inside numbers for power of 3, so on
  */

  /* every term in any power of (x + 1) will always have its sum of the powers inside of it equal the power you raised (x + 1) to get to it*/
```
````

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old post, but I thought I'd share some feedback anyway.

In your comments, you stated that the goal is to expand x + 1 raised to a power, however, your solution allows us to set the variable name and the other number's value. A better description of the goal would be *to raise a binomial consisting of a variable and a constant to an integer power*.

Possibly, the most important thing you could do to improve this script would be break the problem down into sub problems that you could create actors (such as functions or methods of a class) to specifically address. This makes for code that is easier to read and debug.

For example, I can think of several focused sub problems that, if solved, make the overall problem trivial. For example:

- Calculating n choose k
- Calculating the coefficients
- Formatting the terms in the expression
- Generating the overall expansion as a string

One idea might be to wrap the overall problem in a class and the individual sub problems in methods or properties. Here is an example. (Just for fun, I've also allowed the function to be evaluated by calling the object with a value for the variable.)

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;

class Expansion {
  String variable;
  num number;
  int power;

  Expansion(this.variable, this.number, this.power);
  static int _choose(int n, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k > n) return 0;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return _choose(n - 1, k - 1) + _choose(n - 1, k);
  }

  List<num> get coefficients => [
        for (var i = 0; i <= power; i++)
          pow(number, power - i) * _choose(power, i)
      ];

  @override
  String toString() {
    String formatTerm(num coefficient, int power) {
      final c = coefficient < 0
              ? "($coefficient)"
              : coefficient == 1
                  ? ""
                  : "$coefficient",
          p = power == 0 ? "" : "${variable}" + (power == 1 ? "" : "^$power");
      return "${c}$p";
    }

    final cs = coefficients;

    return "($variable ${number > 0 ? "+" : "-"} ${number.abs()})^$power = " +
        [for (var k = 0; k <= power; k++) formatTerm(cs[k], k)].join(" + ");
  }

  num call(num x) => pow(x + number,
      power);
}
```

Now we could, for example, use this class as follows.

```dart
main() {
  final expansion = Expansion("y", 1, 6);
  print(expansion);
  print("If y = 3, the expansion evaluates to ${expansion(3)}");
  expansion
    ..variable = "x"
    ..number = 2
    ..power = 8;
  print(expansion);
  print("If x = 3, the expansion evaluates to ${expansion(3)}");
}
```

Output:

```
(y + 1)^6 =  + 6y + 15y^2 + 20y^3 + 15y^4 + 6y^5 + y^6
If y = 3, the expansion evaluates to 4096
(x + 2)^8 = 256 + 1024x + 1792x^2 + 1792x^3 + 1120x^4 + 448x^5 + 112x^6 + 16x^7 + x^8
If x = 3, the expansion evaluates to 390625
```

Regarding Dart style:

To avoid redundancy in type declarations and to make code more succinct and readable, it is better to avoid such expressions as `List<double> nextLayer = [1, 1]` and replace them with more implicit expressions like `final nextLayer = [1.0, 1.0]`. (Even if we wanted to create an empty list which makes it difficult to imply the type with from the value provided, we could do something like `final output = <String>[]` instead of `List<String> output = []`.). (We can see this convention used, fore example, in [the dart collections documentation](https://dart.dev/language/collections)).